# calculating n-th roots using Python 3's decimal module

Tags: python, math, decimal, nth-root

Is there a built-in way to calculate the correctly rounded n-th root of a Python 3 decimal object?

Comment: do you mean pow(number, 1/n) when you say "nth root"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html), there is a function `power(x,y)` :

> With two arguments, compute x**y. If x is negative then y must be
>   integral. The result will be inexact unless y is integral and the
>   result is finite and can be expressed exactly in ‘precision’ digits.
>   The result should always be correctly rounded, using the rounding mode
>   of the current thread’s context

This implies that power(x, 1.0/n) should give you what you want.

You can also take the nth root with

```
nthRoot = Decimal(x) ** (Decimal(1.0) / Decimal(n) )
```

Not sure if you consider either of these "built in" as you have to compute the reciprocal of n explicitly to get the nth root.